# How to make an array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have this with getters and setters to create one of these but how do I create an array of 12 that can be filled. Also how would I delete cars from the list?

```
Car myCar = new Car(registration, color, make);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear..what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: arrays and list are different data containers, what exactly do you need?

Comment: `Car[] carArray  = new Car[12]`?

Comment: "*I have this with getters and setters to create*" - where are getters and setters. "*how do I create an array of 12 that can be filled*" - what is this "array of 12" .. Please make your question clear.

Comment: Arrays: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html. Collections: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Answer (score 1):

You do it like you would normally do it, except you use your object:

```
Car[] cars = new Car[12];
```

If you want to remove it might be easier to just use a list instead:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
cars.remove(myCar);
```

**EDIT:** More complete example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car myCar = new Car("SS53512", "White", "VW");

    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
    cars.add(myCar);
    System.out.println("Reg.: " + cars.get(0).registration);
    cars.remove(myCar);
}

public static class Car {

    String registration;
    String color;
    String make;

    Car(String registration, String color, String make) {
        this.registration = registration;
        this.color = color;
        this.make = make;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Reg.: SS53512
```

Answer (score 0):

**Array of 12 cars:**

```
Car[] myCars = new Car[12];
```

**Adding cars to array:**

```
//Must construct each car separately
myCars[0] = new Car(registration, color, make);
```

You could "remove" car by setting value to null:

```
myCars[0] = null;
```

**You could also use ArrayList:**

```
//Initialize list
List<Car> myCars = new ArrayList<>();
//Add new car
myCars.add(new Car(registration, color, make));
//Remove car which index inside arraylist corresponds to provided index
myCars.remove(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array

```
Car[] myCars = new Car[] {
        new Car("aaa", Color.YELLOW, "Lotus")
        , new Car("bbb", Color.WHITE, "Rolls-Royce")
        , new Car("ccc", Color.GRAY, "Aston Marin")
};

for (Car myCar : myCars) {
    System.out.println(myCar);
}
```

List

```
List<Car> myCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
myCars.add(new Car("vvv", Color.BLACK, "Audi"));
myCars.add(new Car("yyy", Color.BLUE, "BMW"));
myCars.add(new Car("zzz", Color.red, "Ferari"));

for (Car myCar : myCars) {
    System.out.println(myCar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is declared like any other array -

```
Car[] cars = new Car[12];
```

To assign a value to an element -

```
cars[0] = new Car(registration, color, make);
```

To "remove" an element from the array, as an array is fix sized, you can only change values -

```
cars[0] = null;
```

If you wish to make this expandable, I would suggest using an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
```

And to add a new element to this -

```
cars.add(new Car(registration, color, make);
```

And to remove an element from this -

```
// i is the element to remove.
cars.remove(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Car {
    private String registration;
    private String color;
    private String make;

    public Car(String registration, String color, String make) {
        this.registration = registration;
        this.color = color;
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getRegistration() {
        return registration;
    }

    public void setRegistration(String registration) {
        this.registration = registration;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" + "registration=" + registration + ", color=" + color + ", make=" + make + '}';
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
List<Car> myCar = new ArrayList<>();
myCar.add(new Car("105B","White", "Ford");
myCar.add(new Car("105A","Blue", "Ford");
myCar.add(new Car("105C","Yellow", "Ford");
myCar.remove(0);
for(Car myCars:myCar){
   System.out.println(myCar);
    }


    }
```

Elements are added into the list using add() method and removed using the remove() method.
myCar.remove(0);//removes the first element in the list